# AngularJS give me video url undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, video

I'm trying to read a video name from JSON and to print it in a source of `<video>` tag. But, when I load the page, the video remains blank and in console it says that http://www.url.com/gallery/video/undefined, but if I do "inspection" it prints the right url... why?
This is the HTML code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="mediaReproductionApp">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Principale</title>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular_read_media.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MediaReproductionCtrl">
    <div class="media_player">
        <video preload="metadata" ng-hide="reproductionCodeIsEmpty(item.items[0].media) == true" controls>
            <source src="{{playVideo(item.items[0].media)}}" type="video/webm" />
        </video>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the script:

```
var model = {};

var mediaReproductionApp = angular.module("mediaReproductionApp",[]);

mediaReproductionApp.run(function ($http) {
    $http.get("movimenti_per_totem.json").success(function (data) {
        model.items = data;
    });
});

mediaReproductionApp.controller("MediaReproductionCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.item = model;

    $scope.playVideo = function(media) {
     return "../gallery/video/" + media;
     }

     $scope.reproductionCodeIsEmpty = function(media) {
     return media == "";
     }

});
```

Comment: make sure to use `ng-src` to prevent bad requests of uncompiled url's. Browser doesn't know to wait for angular to compile when it runs into an `src`

Comment: also...until the `$http` is complete `media` is undefined in your function

Comment: @charlietfl so, what I should do?

Comment: with ng-search doesn't work too

Answer (score 1):

Your function `$scope.playVideo()` is going to get called before the data has ever arrived so `media` will be `undefined` initially.

use `ng-src` and make sure not to return a string until `media` is defined. For this reason it's best not to use functions in the view for things like this and define scope model properties to be used in the view instead

```
$scope.playVideo = function(media) {
     return media ? "../gallery/video/" + media : null;
}

<source ng-src="{{playVideo(item.items[0].media)}}" type="video/webm" />
```

`ng-src` won't set an `src` on an element when the interpolated value is falsy

Comment: Now it prints this: <source ng-src="../gallery/video/zafferano_VP8.webm" type="video/webm" src="../gallery/video/zafferano_VP8.webm">
However now it shows me commands, but not the video still...

Comment: is that path correct in relation to the page and route url?

Comment: Yep, I'v just discover that in iFrame it works :/
  <iframe width="560" height="300" ng-src="{{ playVideo(item.items[0].media) }}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen controls></iframe>

Comment: Infact, I'v tried for see if my function could have something wrong grammatically... however I still need HTML5, but I can't understand why it doesn't work...

Comment: no idea either... maybe try removing `preload`. Also might consider putting video tag in template that only gets included when the data exists using `ng-if`  `ng-if ="..." ng-include src='...'`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.The way i called the run method may be wrong.
But im trying to explain here when a scope variable be assigned during a HTTP call.

```
 mediaReproductionApp.run("**xyzw**",function ($http) {
        $http.get("movimenti_per_totem.json").success(function (data) {
            return data;
        });
    });

    mediaReproductionApp.controller("MediaReproductionCtrl",function($scope,xyzw) {


    **xyzw**.success(function(dataresult)){
        $scope.item = dataresult;
    }


        $scope.playVideo = function(media) {
         return "../gallery/video/" + media;
         }

         $scope.reproductionCodeIsEmpty = function(media) {
         return media == "";
         }

    });
```